# How to split big file into multiple files and then access it as single file

Tags: files, fuse

Lets say I have one huge file. Backups using rsync take really long time, even when I change only small parts of it.

Is it possible to split this file into multiple files, and then "mount" it as single file when needed in configuration similar to raid-0? (Compared to raid, I have files without raid metadata, not block devices. Ideally, I would like something simple/standard, without manually creating hundreds of loop devices, one for each file. (I don't even know, if I can create so many loop devices.))

It does not matter too much if combined file behaves as block device or file.